# How can I call an array from one component to show in another component using Class Component in React-js?

Tags: reactjs, arrays, components, react-props, react-class-based-component

I have a question that I believe that is simple, buuut I couldn't solve it and I didn't find something similar on the internet.

I have a React Component that have an array like state and I'm trying to take this array and put in another array into a select-option.

This is the Component with the array:

```
import React,{Component} from "react";


class CarList extends Component{
  constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    carList: ['Jeep', 'Kwid','HB20','Ônix', 'Prisma', 'Gol quadrado']
  }
  }


render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <select>
            {this.state.carList.map( (item,ii)=>{
                return(
                    <option key={ii}>{item}</option>
                )
            } )}
        </select>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


export default CarList;
```

And this is the Component that is render on React-dom:

````
import React from "react";
import { Component } from "react";
import CarList from "./components/Tabela";


class App extends Component{
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state={
    
  }
}



render(){
  return(
    <div>
      <p>I got it! Here is the car list:</p>
      <select>
        {this.state.carList.map(  (item,x)=>{
          return(
            <option key={x}>{item}</option>
          )
        })}
      </select>
    
    </div>
  )
}
}

export default App;```

Hey!

I tried to call with a map();
I tried to import the component;
I tried to call the array just before import the component;
````

Comment: Can you explain more what would you like to happen in the App? Do you want to access the listaCargos property from the CarList in the app?
Or do you simply need to render the select element from CarList? If yes, then it might be enough to just put <CarList /> in the App component

Comment: Hi! I noticed an error in the declaration of the array. I just fixed it.
I need to access the array carList in the App component.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to declare the carList state the App component instead? If the carlist is required inside the Carlist component, you can pass the list as a prop to the child component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understand you correctly. Here is an option:

From checking your App component code, the select component would give the same result as this:

```js
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>I got it! Here is the car list:</p>
        <CarList />
      </div>
    );
  }
```